# Move input control position on screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
.clickBut {
    left: 10px;            /*<<<NO IMPACT*/
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffa500 !important;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.clickRadio {
    left: 200px;         /*<<<NO IMPACT*/
    font-family: verdana;
    left: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Refresh|Reset" onclick="resetRefresh();" class="clickBut" />
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="size" class="clickRadio" checked> Size</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" class="clickRadio"> Count</label>
```

I'm just wondering how I can position these controls away from the top-left corner of the screen. I've tried using `Left` in the `css` for both classes but this has no effect.

Comment: You've to also declare the position property. try position: absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is to wrap them in a div and use `text-align` property

to show them in the right:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Refresh|Reset" onclick="resetRefresh();" class="clickBut" />
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="mode" value="size" class="clickRadio" checked>
         Size
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" class="clickRadio">
        Count
    </label>
</div>
```

to show them in the left :

```
<div style="text-align:left">
        <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Refresh|Reset" onclick="resetRefresh();" class="clickBut" />
        <label>
             <input type="radio" name="mode" value="size" class="clickRadio" checked>
             Size
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" class="clickRadio">
            Count
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use margin-left or padding-left . if they didnt suit your requirement, let us know